# How to hide caret from Text-box in C#?

Tags: winforms, c#-4.0, textbox

I have gone through these links.. [link1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3730968/c-sharp-how-to-disable-cursor-in-textbox) and [link2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/582312/how-to-hide-the-caret-in-a-richtextbox)

But these posts are not so clear..
I need to hide the caret from textbox and make it unselectable.
Please someone help..

Comment: `Label` working fine. Thanks @lc. The plus point of using `label` is that we can align the text in nine forms like left-top, top-middle, middle-center etc., To make a `label` look like `textbox` we should just do `Autosize:false`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The other option is to make the text box read only

Comment: Trap the enter button at form level. Its hard to guess otherwise.

Comment: I was making some mistake with the `Enter` button. This has nothing to do with my application. sorry. @BugFinder