# How can I programmatically make certain parts of a label, in a windows form, bold?

Tags: c#, winforms, fonts

The windows form that I designed has 1 label. The text of this label changes dynamically depending on what data the user selects. Currently i'm creating a string and assigning it to the label's text property. I need a way to make certain parts of the string that I am creating bold. How can I accomplish this in c#?

Comment: [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11311/formatting-text-in-winform-label](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11311/formatting-text-in-winform-label)

Comment: possible duplicate of [Formatting text in WinForm Label](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11311/formatting-text-in-winform-label)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would need to use a custom control for this. You could either write your own or you can use an existing control. On CodeProject there is a control, [GMarkupLabel](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/miscctrl/GMarkupLabel.aspx), that looks good.

Answer (score 2):

You can't format the text inside a `Label`. However, you could use a `RichTextBox` and make it look like a `Label`...

Answer (score 2):

You'll have to create your own label class and draw the text yourself, switching between bold and non-bold font as you need. The standard `Label` class does not support multiple font styles.

Answer (score 2):

Instead of using a Label, you could try using a RichTextBox and make it non-editable.

Answer (score 1):

You can't do it easily. The Font property on a label is for the whole string.

There are two ways to do it :

-You can split your label into two or more labels if the format you want allows this.

-Or you will have to implement your own user control inherited from label.