# Text Formatting Within a .NET Label

Tags: c#, .net, vb.net, winforms, visual-studio-2010

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Make portion of a Label's Text to be styled bold](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2063263/make-portion-of-a-labels-text-to-be-styled-bold)

What is the standard / best practices way to achieve the effect of text formatting within a label in a standard .NET Windows Forms Application?

For example, I want a label I would programatically change.  However, I might want a particular word in the label to be **bold**.

Note: VB.NET answer preferred, C# okay.

Comment: WebForms, WinForms, WPF?

Comment: WinForms (edited question appropriately)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is not possible with the built in label controls. Many third party vendors provide controls with this capability (via HTML-like markup). We have used Telerik's winform suite with success for this.