# Need to change font size

Tags: c#, asp.net

I need a function which will check for a string in a text. (May be label/textbox text).

The function should check if a particular text exist in it, then if found it should make it bold.

How this should be done?

Comment: (or indeed, any of about a dozen UI layers)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you mean ASP.NET then such code will work:

```
string myString = "The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog";
string textToReplace = "fox";
myString = myString.Replace(textToReplace, "<span style=\"font-weight: bold;\">" + textToReplace + "</span>");
```

Then apply the string as Text of a label. You can't make text bold inside textbox.

The above example will make the word *fox* bold.

Answer (score 1):

EDIT: This answer applies to WinForms only.

The Label control does not allow partial formatting - which means that each formatting style you apply will affect the whole string.

The RichTextBox component allows you to do partial formatting - i.e applying a style on a specific word in the text.

More on RichTextBox can be found [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.richtextbox.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

Here i found an answer that its possible (offcourse it is, almost everything is possible, haha :P).

[Make portion of a Label's Text to be styled bold](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2063263/make-portion-of-a-labels-text-to-be-styled-bold)

Answer (score -1):

Lets, suppose the Label variable is label,

You can do if using desktop application,

```
**if(label.Text != string.Empty)
{
 label.Font.Bold = true;
}**
```

and if you are using Asp.Net you have to do it using **javascript** if want to do it on the **client side**.

If you want to make portion od a label text bold, it is **not allowed** by the framework, rather you could take multiple labels for that.

Comment: He want only part bold, not the whole Label. And it's possible with server side code in ASP.NET

Comment: i am using Asp.Net. The function should be in csharp as i have to do some validation. and if it becomes true then it should be highlighted/ bold. on web page.