# .NET WinForms several styles in a label

Tags: .net, winforms, coding-style, label

.NET WinForms several styles in a label

Comment: possible duplicate of [Formatting text in WinForm Label](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11311/formatting-text-in-winform-label)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I used one of these:

1. Use a container control (Panel) and add several labels each with its own style.
2. Paint yourself by overriding using the Paint event

Comment: you don't have to paint yourself if you already have multiple label styles.  +1, however