# Different Fonts in one Label

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2008, fonts, label

does anybody know a way how to create a Label(WindowsForms) with two different Fonts or at least two different FontSizes?

Comment: possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11311/formatting-text-in-winform-label

Comment: @Lee Sy En: your right, thanks for showing. Is the rigth behaiviour in this forum to delete my question know??

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think you should override default label `onPaint` method and draw multiple text/fonts manually using Graphics.
Take a look at this [example](http://ondotnet.com/pub/a/dotnet/2002/03/18/customcontrols.html).

Comment: the (specific) link has broken.

Answer (score 2):

Try to `override` or handle `paint` event (method) use classes from `System.Drawing` namespace.

Answer (score 2):

You have to create your own drawing using GDI also try to find out if you can find any other third party controls that support your need !! Hopefully you might get them.

Answer (score -1):

you can do that things with usercontrol wpf
first of all from add item search usercontrol 
and after that in the xml of builder name grid like t1
and in the code of it type this code

```
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    sb.Append(@"<TextBlock   xmlns='http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation' 
                    xmlns:x='http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml'> ");
    sb.Append(@"  Hello <Bold>my</Bold> faithful <Underline>computer</Underline>.<Italic>You rock!</Italic>");
    sb.Append(@"</TextBlock> ");
    TextBlock myButton = (TextBlock)XamlReader.Parse(sb.ToString());
    t1.Children.Add(myButton);
```

and run it and change it in a new manner.