# Can I have 2 foreground colors in a control?

Tags: winforms, devexpress

I'm using DevExpress WinForms controls, and I was wondering whether I can set the font color a cell to be something like "first word in black, second word in red".

Is this possible? Is setting different font colors per control even possible in DevExpress? How about in WinForms at all?

If not, can I use a different, "crazier" approach to get this? Use 2 label controls per cell maybe?

Comment: The answer at
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11311/formatting-text-in-winform-label should help you.

Comment: The question you have linked to relates to standard Winforms and not DevExpress controls which do have the functionality requested.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It depends on exactly which control you want to do this with.

The controls that support Html formatting (and how to activate it) are listed [here](http://documentation.devexpress.com/#WindowsForms/CustomDocument4874).