# Formatting Text in a ListView?

Tags: c#, listview, formatting, listviewitem

I'm creating a little app that will read, parse, and format the contents of a lua script - specifically, a *SavedVariables* file from *World of Warcraft* created by the "Elephant" chat logging add-on. The prototype I have in mind will generate an array of `ListViewItem` instances, showing a timestamp, player name, what channel the message was posted into, and the message that was posted.

I'd like to have the chat message rendered as it would be in the game: the game colors the names of those "talking" in the chat after their character's class (e.g. a rogue's name is yellow, mages' names are light blue), but when it comes to `ListViewItem` and `ListViewSubItem`, coloring text there seems to be an all-or-nothing deal.

Would it be possible to add functionality for the `ListView` to apply formatting (or just color) to text in a `ListViewItem` or `ListViewSubItem` based on markup in the `Text` property?

EDIT: I'm asking if it's possible to just add text formatting to a ListViewItem through the magic of inheritance/polymorphism in a derived class, and if so, what's the best way to do it (amount of effort, code security, etc)?

Comment: It would seem that you'll have to create a custom `ListView` control. See [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/11323/1244630) for a similar question about formatting a `Label`.

Comment: I figured that I'd have to make a custom ListView, ListViewItem, or ListViewSubItem. I wasn't clear enough - I'm asking if it's possible to just add text formatting to a ListViewItem through the magic of inheritance/polymorphism in a derived class, and what's the best way to do it (amount of effort, code security, etc). I'll edit my question to reflect this.

Answer (score 1):

Speaking from a *Windows Forms* usage view point, you can render the items manually. However you should also consider situations such as: how should the text be rendered when the text exceeds the bounds of the `Control`/column?

This only requires that you inherit from `ListView`; you can render each item using:

```cs
protected override void OnDrawItem(DrawListViewItemEventArgs e)
```

Of course, `OwnerDraw` must be set to `true`. `DrawListViewItemEventArgs` contains the text that needs to be rendered and the `Graphics` instance that should be used to render the text. You could then use `DrawString(string s, Font font, Brush brush, float x, float y)` to render each part of the text as required by your mark-up convention.

If you don't mind the GPL, [`ObjectListView`](http://objectlistview.sourceforge.net) does offer more formatting options but perhaps it is not as flexible as you require.

Since a `RichTextBox` does allows flexible text formatting, I wonder if it could somehow be used as a renderer...

Answer (score 0):

im not completely sure this would work and I cant really test it, but it might be worth a try

```
<ListViewItem>
   <ContentPresenter>
       <TextBlock>
          <Run x:Name="playerName" Foreground="Blue" Text="NAME"/>
          <Run x:Name="etc" Foreground="Black" Text="..."/>
        </TextBlock>
     </ContentPresenter>
 </ListViewItem>
```

The basic idea here is that in the list box item you have a the content presenter that I think holds the textblock. Within this you can set individual Run tags (bits of individual text) and you can format each one differently. you should also be able to set the text programmatically when the run tags are assigned names