# how to display a single word in bold font in a sentence?

Tags: c#, winforms, user-interface, label

I want to display the **text2** as bold font

```
   public partial class Form2 : Form
   {
        public Form2(string text1, string text2, string text3, double text4,string t)
        {
           InitializeComponent();
           label1.Text = text1;
           label2.Text = "On  " + text2 +
                         "  Or When Your Vehicle Runs  " + text3 + " KM. ";
           label3.Text ="Today "+ t +
                        "  and It Reminds You " + text4 +" Days Earlir.";
        }
   }
```

Comment: Me too; what have *you* tried thus far :)?

Comment: Looking to the page inherit this must be the Windows FORMS application.  Why this question is tagged with asp.net, html ?

Comment: Can's do that in Windows Forms, see accepted answer in this post http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11311/formatting-text-in-winform-label

Comment: You can try adding new labels and combining them to achieve the effect you want. And also arranging them next to each other.

Answer (score 1):

You can't do it directly on Windows forms .

Try like this

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/31237/GMarkupLabel-A-C-Windows-Forms-control-to-display

Answer (score 1):

Here is a lightweight Label class that supports emphasized test.

**Edit** : After visiting CodeReview I have updated my answer. It is much more robust now. It still uses a Label subclass. You can create strong text like this:

```
This is *bold* and this is an \* asterisk.
```

for your question you would write:

```
label2.Text = "On  *" + text2 + "*  Or When Your Vehicle Runs  " + text3 + " KM. ";
```

Just add the class to your project, adapt its namespace, compile, drag from the toolbox and change its extended properties like a plain `Label`.

You can set both a `StrongColor` and a `StrongFont` to whatever you like. Default is `ControlText` and the `Label.FontStyle.Bold`.

You can change the formatting string `Splitter`from the asterisk (`*`) to anthing and you can escape it by a '`\`' or whatever `Escape`  string you want, as both are exposed as Properties.

The `FmtLabel` will autosize its Width and is meant for one line of text only.

You may want to have a look at an expanded version [here on CodeReview](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/55916/a-lightweight-rich-link-label). At under 200 lines of code it is still rather small, will support multiple lines, up to 10 fonts and even multiple interactive links. (Updated Version 2 soon to come)

```
using System;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace yourNamespace
{
  public class FmtLabel : Label
  {
    public FmtLabel()
    {
        this.Paint += FmtLabel_Paint;
        Escape = @"\";
        Splitter = "*";
        AutoSize = true;
    }

    public string Splitter    { get; set; }
    public string Escape      { get; set; }
    public Font   StrongFont  { get; set; }
    public Color  StrongColor { get; set; }

    private SolidBrush textBrush, backBrush, strongBrush;

    protected override void OnPaint(PaintEventArgs e) { FmtLabel_Paint(this, e); }

    public void FmtLabel_Paint(object sender, PaintEventArgs e)
    {
        if (StrongColor == Color.Empty) StrongColor = SystemColors.ControlText;
        textBrush = new SolidBrush(ForeColor);
        backBrush = new SolidBrush(BackColor);
        strongBrush = new SolidBrush(StrongColor);

        e.Graphics.FillRectangle(backBrush, this.ClientRectangle);
        if (this.Text.Length <= 0) return;

        if (Splitter == null) Splitter = "*";
        int strongStart = Text.StartsWith(Splitter) ? 0 : 1;

        StringFormat SF = new StringFormat(StringFormat.GenericTypographic)
                    { FormatFlags = StringFormatFlags.MeasureTrailingSpaces };

        float x = 0f;  // tracks the write pointer

        string text_ = escapes(this.Text, true);
        string[] parts = text_.Split(new string[] { Splitter }, 
                                     StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
        // plain and strong text will alternate
        for (int i = 0; i < parts.Length; i++)
        {
           string p = escapes(parts[i], false);
           if (i % 2 == strongStart)
           {
              e.Graphics.DrawString(p, StrongFont, textBrush, new Point((int)x, 0));
              x += e.Graphics.MeasureString(p, StrongFont, Point.Empty, SF).Width + 2;
           }
           else
           {
              e.Graphics.DrawString(p, this.Font, textBrush, new Point((int)x, 0));
              x += e.Graphics.MeasureString(p, this.Font, Point.Empty, SF).Width + 2;
           }
        }

        this.Width = (int)x;
        textBrush.Dispose();
        backBrush.Dispose();
        strongBrush.Dispose();
    }

    string escapes(string input, bool escape)
    {
        if (escape)  return input.Replace(Escape + Splitter, ((char)1).ToString());
        else         return input.Replace(((char)1).ToString(), Splitter);  // unescape
    }

  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

WinForms don't allow to do it.

but

You'll need to put the text into a RichTextBox and have the name as a separate Run in the Paragraph as in this example from the MSDN:

```
// Create a Run of plain text and some bold text.
Run myRun1 = new Run();
myRun1.Text = "A RichTextBox with ";
Bold myBold = new Bold();
myBold.Inlines.Add("initial content ");
Run myRun2 = new Run();
myRun2.Text = "in it.";

// Create a paragraph and add the Run and Bold to it.
Paragraph myParagraph = new Paragraph();
myParagraph.Inlines.Add(myRun1);
myParagraph.Inlines.Add(myBold);
myParagraph.Inlines.Add(myRun2);

// Add the paragraph to the RichTextBox.
MyRTB.Blocks.Add(myParagraph);
```