# Underline a single word in List & Label

Tags: c#, report, reporting, designer, listlabel

I'm creating a form in **combit** **List&Label 16** and trying to underline a single word in a label but I can't find the option to do so...

Do you know if and how I can to this?

The way I did it now is to split the label in 3 parts and to underline the middle one but I refuse to believe that this is the way to go in 2015 :D

Thanks in advance

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11311/formatting-text-in-winform-label

Comment: Hi Praveen Paulose thanks for your comment but this question is about List&Label 16 and your comment is about winforms :)

Comment: @xeraphim you shouldn't have used the tag `forms` then and I doubt whether `forms` is appropriate. You *should* have added some reporting tag. Don't expect people to know the product you use. You should also explain how/why this is a programming question instead of eg a general usage question which is out of scope. Perhaps you should contact the company's customer support. Did you check their site, documentation, support section etc?

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos you're right about the forms tag.. I used it because I'm creating a form but the correct tag is reporting. I expect people to know the product I use because I specifically mentioned it in the title and in the question so everyone who really read the question should know that it isn't about winforms :) I did check their site & documentation but couldn't find anything which is why I'm posting here. I hoped someone uses List&Label too and can help me out

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the `Formatted Text` object instead of unformatted text. This gives you all the options to format single words.

Comment: I knew there must be a way to do it without splitting the label, thank you so much! I don't know how I could overlook this object. Thanks! :-)