# How to bold a part of string being passed into TextBox in c#

Tags: c#, winforms

I have a string builder where value is appending at runtime via placeholder. Once string builder has appended, it is assigned to a text box (not rich txt) to show up in UI.

I want part of the text to be bold.

```
sb.AppendFormat("Added {0} by {1}:\n{2}", DateTime.ToString(), userName, note);
txt.Text = sb.ToString();
```

Expected output:

> **Added 9/01/2016 8:47:19 PM by Vinoth:** Testing Purpose

How can I achieve this? Is there anyway of looping over words with the `:` symbol until I want it to be bold?

Comment: Text box does not support multiple font styles like that.

Comment: You can create a `TextBox` child class and override the `OnPaint` method and drawing the text manually (`e.Graphics.DrawString(...)`). Or you can use 2 `TextBox` (one bold and one normal). Or simpler, use a `RichTextBox`.

Comment: Just use a RichTextBox. It's not as hard as you think.

Comment: @MatthewWatson - how do you know he thinks it's hard?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Formatting text in WinForm Label](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11311/formatting-text-in-winform-label)

Comment: He is using TextBox not label, can not be said as duplicate.

Comment: subclassing TextBox is not recommended. Subclassing a Label to show different font styles is simple.. You do realize that your example contains not one but __three__ colons??

Comment: @TaW yes i forget that point. I've asked client for RTB. Thanks for your comments

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You will have to build up the text in sections.

Either as different TextBoxes/TextBlocks or as a single RichTextBox with separate Runs for the sections you want in a different style.

Comment: Thank you...planning for RTB